# Getting HTTP-404 error while running spring MVC application in Eclipse - Tutorials point hello world example

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am a beginner to Spring i am learning from tutorials point , Below code is exactly as it is in the Tutorials point but when i try to run it i am getting 404 error, the code is hello world program when i run on eclipse using tomcat server i am getting error like this

The url i am using on browser is  http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello

HelloController.java:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my directory structure

HelloWeb Project:

```
|--HelloController.java
|-- WebContent
   `-- WEB-INF
         |-- jsp
              |-- web.xml
```

Comment: What URL did you try to access?  Can you see the Tomcat homepage when you access `http://localhost:8080/` ?

Comment: what url are you hitting?

Comment: Yeah i am able to access tomcat home page http://localhost:8080/

Comment: try hitting http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello

Comment: i am running in eclipse so when i run on java file a web page opens in eclipse with url: http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

Comment: That is also giving same problem Url: localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello

Comment: Please look at @Raghu 's comment above.  You were trying to directly access a JSP page, which is not possible.

Comment: Yeah i am trying on my browser also using url:  localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello
even then i am getting 404 error

Comment: The whole point of an MVC framework is to NEVER hit a view (a JSP) directly, but to ALWAYS go through a controller. And BTW, everything under WEB-INF is, by design, inaccessible from the outside. Hit the URL of the controller: `/HelloWeb/hello`. Also, the web.xml file must be directly under WEB-INF. Not under WEB-INF/jsp

Comment: I am testing on both eclipse and browser on browser url: localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello

and on eclipse url:http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

Comment: what is your root context? to check Go to Servers->tomcat->double click on the module and check the path value. if path value is just "/", then http://locahost:8080/hello would work. suppose if path is "/helloApp" then http://localhost:8080/helloApp/hello should work.

Comment: there is no module in tomcat folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/05/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/#hello_world

Follow the above URL , it works completely I have tried and make sure you have added dependencies for spring in pom.xml.
Also in your webapp folder HelloWeb-servlet.xml should also be present.